# Expo app crashes on iOS where can I see my error log ? (Because of Redux)

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I run this command:

```
npx expo start --no-dev --minify
```

On Android its not crashed but on iOS (iphone) its crash. They are no errors. So where can I see the error log ?

After trying debugging I find out when I remove provider={store=} then its works. So the problem is there.

But what I am doing wrong ? in dev mode it works perfect also in production android.

App.tsx

```
enableScreens(true);

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Fredoka_medium: require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf'),
        Fredoka_light: require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf'),
        Fredoka_regular: require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf'),
      });
    //  const userToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('UserSecureToken');
    const userToken = 2121;
      if(userToken) {
        setReady(true);
      } else {
       // await SecureStore.setItemAsync('UserSecureToken', 'test_token');
        setReady(true);
      }
    })()
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (ready) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [ready]);

  if(!ready) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={s.rootView}>
          <GestureHandlerRootView style={s.rootView}>
            <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}>
              <Host>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
              </Host>
              <Toast position='bottom' config={ToastConfig} />
            </NavigationContainer>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </Provider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Api } from "./apis/api";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [Api.reducerPath]: Api.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().
  concat(Api.middleware),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export default store;
```

So how can I now see the error log is there a tool for expo ?